# React Table - new order after filtering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have a table made with React Table. I want it to have a fresh order after each filtering. So far, I have achieved only one order which is created at render.

Here is the Table component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Table as BTable } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useTable, useSortBy, useGlobalFilter } from "react-table";

function Table({ data, columns, variant, filter = "" }) {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    state,
    setGlobalFilter,
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
    },
    useGlobalFilter,
    useSortBy
  );

  const { globalFilter } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    setGlobalFilter(filter);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <span>Search: </span>
      <input
        value={globalFilter}
        onChange={(e) => setGlobalFilter(e.target.value)}
        onMouseMove={(e) => setGlobalFilter(e.target.value)}
      ></input>
      <hr></hr>
      <BTable striped bordered hover variant={variant} {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th
                  width={column.width}
                  {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}
                >
                  {column.render("Header")}
                  <span>
                    {column.isSorted
                      ? column.isSortedDesc
                        ? " "
                        : " "
                      : ""}
                  </span>
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {rows.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </BTable>
    </>
  );
}

export default Table;
```

And implementation:

```
const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "#",
        Cell: (row) => {
          return <div>{Number(row.row.id) + 1}</div>;
        },
      },
      {
        Header: "ID",
        accessor: "id",
      },
      {
        Header: "Added By",
        accessor: "addedBy",
      },
      { Header: "Date of creation", accessor: "dateOfCreation", width: "10%" },
      {
        Header: "Ordertaker",
        accessor: "orderTaker",
        width: "5%",
      },
      {
        Header: "Customer",
        accessor: "customer",
        width: "20%",
      },
      {
        Header: "Description",
        accessor: "description",
        disableSortBy: "true",
        width: "30%",
      },
      {
        Header: "Status",
        accessor: "status",
        disableSortBy: "true",
        width: "10%",
      },
    ],
  );

return (
            <Table
              data={data} // data is fetched from firebase
              columns={columns}
              variant="dark"
            />
  );
```

"#" column has number from 1 for each row. What I want is to reset order in "#" column after each filtering to start with 1. Any ideas how can it be done?

Comment: You could use `array.map((item, index)=> ...)` then use `index+1` in your `#` column.

Comment: @David784 Could you show me an example and post it as answer?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution on the internet. Here`s the [link](https://github.com/TanStack/react-table/discussions/2974)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`map` returns are inherently ordered in the insertion order. You could try a `sort` before hand. [Here's a link.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Something like this might work:

```js
rows.sort((a, b) => a.# - b.#).map((row, i) => ...
```

Comment: Sure, but where do I put this code to work with React Table`s globalFilter?